# Has the set of all ideals of a ring a ring-like structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

After learning about ideals of a ring and the basic operations that can be made with them, I started wondering about the following situation.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity (for simplicity), and denote by $I(R)$ the set of all ideals of $R$. The **sum** of two ideals, $I$ and $J$, is given by: $I+J=\{i+j:i \in I,j \in J\}$, and their **product** is: $IJ=\{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i:x_i \in I, y_i \in J, n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast \}$. Then:

$i)$ $(I(R),+)$ is a commutative monoid, with identity element $(0)$;

$ii)$ $(I(R),\cdot)$ is also a commutative monoid, with identity element $R$;

$iii)$ We have distributivity: $I(J+K)=IJ+IK$ and $(I+J)K=IK+JK$, for $I,J,K \in I(R)$.

Now my questions:

$1)$ Are all of the above, $i),ii),iii)$ correct? I am quite unsure about the product being associative (I failed to prove for myself, so any proof/indication would be appreciated). The other axioms seem to hold.

$2)$ If $1)$ is true, then what type of structure is $(I(R),+,\cdot)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The “semiring of ideals of a ring” is definitely something people have studied.  The fact that its + operation is idempotent is also a feature.

Comment: I imagine this, but I just started learning about ideals, and the results i),ii) and iii) were not presented in my algebra class, I individually thought about them. Also, I just want to make sure that I am on the right path.

Comment: truth be told, I’ve never found a use for the observation.  Beyond rephrasing some things we usually say, it did not buy much in the way of insights.

Comment: @rschwieb I disagree with that. The question the OP asks is natural and from time to time these results get used (especially the associativity of the ideals, when working with prime rings for example).

Comment: @QuantumSpace It sounds like you are disagreeing with the claim “it is useless and not natural” which is nothing like what I said.  Of course it is natural, and I’m saying my experience is that it has not yielded insights, just rephrasing.  Do you have a case where a semiring theoretic insight yielded something useful?

Comment: @rschwieb I misinterpreted  what you wrote. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

''ii)  (I(R),⋅) is also a commutative monoid, with identity element, again, (0);''

Identity element $R$.

''2)  If 1) is true, then what type of structure is (I(R),+,⋅)?''

Its a semiring.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited the identity element. My mistake. I knew it was $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your claims are all true. To see the associativity $(IJ)K = I(JK)$ (as you asked), take an element
$x \in (IJ)K$.
It can be written as
$$x = \sum_i a_ib_i$$
with $a_i \in IJ$ and $b_i \in K$. We can further write $a_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}  x_j^i y_j^i$ with $x_j^ i \in I$ and $y_j^i \in J$. Thus
$$x= \sum_i \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} (x_j^iy_j^i)b_i = \sum_i \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} x_j^i (y_j^i b_i) \in I(JK)$$
and the other inclusion is similar. We thus see that your associativity follows from associativity of ring multiplication, as could be expected.

Comment: Thank you. At the end of the day, I realized why my proof didn't work.